# Inject Cookies into a WebView

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I am calling a service to get Cookies as a JSONArray that looks like this

```
{"domain":"blabla.com","expirationDate":1896127200,"hostOnly":false,"httpOnly":false,"name":"__ssid","path":"\/","sameSite":"no_restriction","secure":false,"session":false,"storeId":"0","value":"392997aa-ce67-4d96-a73d-de0ad794f7bf","id":1}
```

then parsing these cookies like this

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder()
                        .domain(checkDomain(jsonObject.optString("domain")))
                        .expiresAt(jsonObject.optLong("expirationDate"))
                        .name(jsonObject.optString("name"))
                        .path(jsonObject.optString("path"))
                        .value(jsonObject.optString("value"))
                        .build();
```

then injecting the cookies like this

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    } else {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();


    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            String cookieString = cookie.name() + "=" + cookie.value() + "; domain=" + cookie.domain();
            cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.domain(), cookieString);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }
    }
```

but when i load `https://blabla.com` into the WebView cookies are not working, am i missing anything?

Please help

Comment: Any critics on my answer?

Comment: Is the `cookie.domain()` the same for multiple values in the array? If so, it is being replaced like a Hashmap. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I worked with, it works perfectly fine:

```
    CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(treeUrl, cookieString);            
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    webView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
```

If you have to inject a JSON to cookies, just use yourJson.toString()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to set cookies.

```
web_view = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(web_view.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie(URL,"uniqueId=10028; Domain=.codean.app");
    cookieSyncManager.sync();

    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(URL);

    Log.e(TAG, ""+cookie);
    web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web_view.loadUrl(URL);
```

Output:

```
2019-09-16 15:20:21.412 31408-31408/com.sam.webviewtest E/MainActivity: uniqueId=10028
2019-09-16 15:20:22.204 31408-31408/com.sam.webviewtest E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-09-16 15:20:22.205 31408-31408/com.sam.webviewtest E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

[image]

For testing purpose, you can use below url

```
https://codean.app/so/cookies.php
```

in this php file, it only output all the cookies

```
<pre><?php print_r( $_COOKIE ); ?></pre>
```

I've used the same url in my above example,

Comment: testing url is not working anymore.

Comment: @AmirDora. the domain was expired a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
private fun setCookie(){
val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
cookieManager.acceptCookie()

val domain = "https://www.yourdomain.com"

webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
webViewTest.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webViewTest.loadUrl(domain)

cookieManager.setCookie(domain,"$cookieKey=$cookieValue")
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view.webViewTest,true)
```

}

Comment: `cookieManager.acceptCookie()` is a getter, not a setter